# Подтверждение адреса сервера \\ VK CallBackAPI

Tags: vkontakte-api, express

Создал следующую функцию with express для отслеживания POST запроса исходящего от вк.

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
res.status(200).send('Confirm string'); 
});
```

после чего включаю сервер, захожу в интерфейс вк и отправляю запрос, на который мой сервер должен вернуть "Confirm string", но ответ от моего сервера не прилетает.

Comment: А сам запрос приходит на сервер? Твоя функция получает управление?

Comment: запрос приходит на сервер, но как мне сказали в ТП вк: 'мы не получаем ответ от Вашего сервера вовсе, либо получаем 503 код'

Comment: Твоя функция получает управление?

Comment: HTTP 503 Service Unavailable код состояния сервера, указывающий на то, что `сервер не готов обработать данный запрос`. Т.е. до твоей функции даже дело может не дойти...

Comment: я понимаю что значат 500-е коды, мне бы решение найти для этой проблемы,, сейчас сделаю эдит и добавлю весь код, мне кажется, я упустил что то важное:)